# Xcode won't start after OS update

Tags: xcode, macos-high-sierra

I just updated my macOS to 10.13.3 supplemental with the Telugu fix. Now I can not start Xcode 9.2 anymore.

```
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftDispatch.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
  Reason: image not found
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Same crash with a fresh installed XCode 9.3 beta 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirming that Avast Business Antivirus broke my Xcode. To fix it, I made sure OSX was updated, then I opened Avast, opened Virus Chest, and restored libswiftDispatch.dylib then restarted my machine.

Comment: my virus scanner was broken after the update, so could not restore the files from the quarantine.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that AVG anti virus placed the libswiftDispatch.dylib in quarantine as a false positive. Multiple programs on my Mac failed to start due to this reason.

I removed the AVG app and reinstalled XCode to get everything working again.